# How can I specify Office in webpack

Tags: webpack, office-js, outlook-addin, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

I'm trying to use webpack in a previously working outlook addin; as I understand, to make the addin work in "old" Outlook, I have to include Office. The Microsoft Documentation assumes Office is specified in index.html. Confused. Help appreciated.

Comment: The only reason I use `webpack` is for transpiling/babelifying to have Add-Ins function using `IE`. Generally, I've noticed that MSFT has FORCED Edge Webview 2 Runtime on all computers now and you likely don't have any users w/ IE setup and don't need webpack at all.

Answer (score 1):

`Webpack` and `OfficeJS` are entirely different and not related to each other entities. [Webpack](https://webpack.js.org/) is a bundle tool which can process all files used by your web application (not necessarily Office add-in) while OfficeJS is a library which provides the interop layer between Office applications and your web application/add-in.

> I'm trying to use webpack in a previously working outlook addin; as I understand, to make the addin work in "old" Outlook, I have to include Office.

It is not clear what you mean by `old` Outlook. But in such cases I'd suggest scaffolding a new add-in solution by using the yeoman generator and see how `webpack` is used in the add-in solution.

Answer (score 0):

I also posted a closely related question on GitHub, which includes my answer to the question(s) I was struggling with; might help someone:
[Outlook Add-In problems in Old Outlook](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js/issues/3783)

Re above, yes - I don't need webpack, mostly needed to get package.json right, and .babelrc

In case anyone's interested in what M/S are doing with Outlook, try [New Outlook](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/getting-started-with-the-new-outlook-for-windows-656bb8d9-5a60-49b2-a98b-ba7822bc7627)

Thanks for tips